# cakephp sql join query in controller

Tags: sql, cakephp, join, controller

I'm new to CakePHP and stuck on this situation:

I'm developing a test system and I have following three tables:  **Category, SubCategory, Test**

When I create a test, I store `category_id`, `subcategory_id` with other data in Test table
Now in `TestsController`, I want to read the number of records & rows matched by the query

I wish to execute queries similar to these:

**Query 1**

```
select count(*) from Test where user_id='$user_id' and category_id=$category_id and subcategory_id=$subcategory_id
```

**Query 2**

```
select 
a.test_id,
a.test_name,
a.user_id,
a.test_type,
a.create_date,
a.create_time,
a.category_id,
a.subcategory_id,
a.randomize,
a.test_password
from Test a, Category b, SubCategory c 
where user_id='$user_id' and 
a.category_id=$category_id and
a.subcategory_id=$subcategory_id and
a.category_id=b.category_id and
a.subcategory_id=c.subcategory_id
```

Now, I don't want (I actually don't know) to use the $hasMany, $belongsTo etc.

I simply want to execute these queries in Controller & pass the data to the view

Note: In all simple cases, I used the CakePHP style of coding

I wish to know, how can I get an array of rows after executing **Query 2**
Is it possible to execute such query directly (like mysql_query)

Answer (score 1):

you could create a function in Test Model and access the query, like:

```
class TestModel extends Model {
    ..
    public function getQueryData($user_id, $cat_id, $subcat_id) {
       return $this->query("SELECT a.test_id, a.test_name ..... ;");
    }
}
```

and in Test controller, you could do:

```
$this->loadModel("Test");
$result = $this->Test->getQueryData($user_id, $cat_id, $subcat_id);
```